# How is size of record size set for each record in kafka partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to know if each record within a kafka topic occupies same size irrespective actual size of the message?

I am aware of the following property -> `max.message.bytes=1000012`, this will make size of a record upto `1000012` bytes.

My question is if incoming record is less than these bytes , what will be the actual size of the space which is set aside for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kafka, the broker appends to disk pretty much exactly what the producer has sent.

However as you hinted, the producer wraps the message into a record and a batch.

The full description of these data structures can be found in the [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#messageformat).

Apart for very small messages, the disk space occupied by a message depends mostly of its size as the Kafka overhead per message is relatively small.

For example, for a single message of 10 bytes without a key or headers, the size on disk will be 78 bytes. That may seem like a large overhead but as it is almost constant regardless of the message size, if the payload was 1024 bytes, the total disk occupied would only be 1094 bytes.

If you take batching into account, then the overhead diminishes even further as the batch header (~50 bytes) will be used for several records.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My current understanding is that whatever is received by kafka it is stored in kafka topic's offset. So if I receive message-1 , it would be stored at an offset, similarly for message-2 it would be stored at next offset. But I am not aware of "batching".  How will some batch come? Can you help in understanding or provide some link?

Comment: The offset has no link to the size. You can have a 10MB message at offset 0 and a 1k message at offset 1. Kafka Records are always part of a batch but the producer can also include several records in a batch to reduce the overall size and improve throughput, see the Producer settings `linger.ms` and `batch.size` http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs

Answer (score 2):

According to [Kafka Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/),

> `max.message.bytes`: The largest record batch size allowed by Kafka. If this is increased
>   and there are consumers older than 0.10.2, the consumers' fetch size
>   must also be increased so that the they can fetch record batches this
>   large.

As far as I understand you are asking whether every message will reserve a space equal to `max.message.bytes`.

The answer is no. `max.message.bytes` defines the maximum permitted size of a message and not the size of every message.